# Collation configuration in SQL Server 2005 Express setup

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I had to re-install my SQL Server 2005 Express instance due to a conflict with collations.

Now, once in the setup, I can't see the SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI collation, I see "Latin1_General" instead, and I've been told is not the same.

Could you please tell me where I can find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CI and AI bits mean "Case Insensitive" and "Accent Insenstive" (which are checkboxes in the installation dialog if I remember correctly).  The CP1 part is, I think, "Code Page 1" and refers to the US region whereas without CP1, it refers to the UK region (or maybe, more generally, non-US English) - this may also be a separate selection in the installation dialog.

If you don't se these options, it will default to the codepage most suitable for the *system default* international settings in Windows (note: this may not be the same as *your profile's* international settings) *at the time of installation*.  You can change these (both yours and the system default) via the control panel.

**UPDATE:**

I've downloaded and run through the installation for SQL Server Express 2005 (SP3)...

I deselected "Hide advanced configuration options" on the "Registration Information" page (but not sure if this was necessary).  On the Collation Settings" page I selected "SQL collations (used for compatibility...)" and then "Dictionary order, case-insensitive, accent-insensitive, for use with 1252 Character Set". Everything else was left on defaults.

The result was a SQL Server Express 2005 installation using the SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI collation.

More information on this topic can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I see those check boxes. I didn't know what AI and CI meant.

Comment: I'm sorry, that didn't solve my problem. What you told me is for Latin1_General_CI_AI, but I need the collation that begins with "SQL": SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AI. I've been told that I have to check something from the Background settings but I don't know what.

Comment: This may be useful: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=69031.  Are yu doing a custom or default installation?  If you do a custom installtion yo can choose the collation explicitly (just choose US English if given the option)

Comment: I've updaed my response with what I hope is a definitive answer.